# Form POST from other domain is empty in PHP

Tags: php, apache, post, http-post

When posting a form (using POST) from another domain, my POST collection is empty.
And when I test with a simple HTML page on the same domain it works.

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", true);
echo("input: " . file_get_contents("php://input"));
?>
```

Does anyone have an idea? Could it be a server setting/configuration?

These are the headers I get back (when using Postman):

```
Connection →Upgrade, Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Length →27
Content-Type →text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date →Wed, 17 Jan 2018 10:39:26 GMT
Keep-Alive →timeout=2, max=100
Server →Apache/2.4.29 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2k
Upgrade →h2,h2c
Vary →Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
X-Powered-By →PHP/7.2.0
access-control-allow-origin →*
```

Comment: please share the request code as well.

Answer (score 0):

The php://input is a read only stream, read raw data from the request body. It is useful when data comes in json format for example. When you post a form with enctype=multipart/formdata the data (key value pairs) is in the $_POST global variable, and the php://input is not available.